# Having trouble in tracing code in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently struggling with this piece of code

```
@play = current_user.playlist.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

What does `current_user.playlist.find_by_id()` mean? How can I trace this code to find current_user, playlist and find_by_id() function?

Comment: I think this means `find by id the playlist of the current user` but hey, I'm not sure !

Comment: Active Record provides a finder method for field `id`. You may take a look at [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)

Comment: What kinds of clowns voted to close this question? Knowing how to debug code you're not familiar with a is a damn useful skill.

Comment: @ChrisHeald Even after seeing the `NoMethodError: undefined method destroy for nil:NilClass` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could be using devise, if that is the case, `current_user` returns an instance of class `User` which is the currently logged in user. Or `nil` if there is no logged in user.

`playlist` is a method defined in class `User`, you should find this class in `app/models/user.rb`, usually this method would be defined with:

```
has_one :playlist
```

or:

```
belongs_to :playlist
```

`find_by_id` is a method defined by Rails for class `User`, you won't see this directly in file. It is created when you have something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
```

`ActiveRecord::Base` creates a lot of methods more.

## Debug your code

I would print each part of the sentence

```
p current_user
p current_user.playlist
p params[:id]
p current_user.playlist.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

and check results in my server console, you could spot which of these is the first `nil`.

Comment: juanpastas: Thanks for your reply. I am keep getting this error with this code `NoMethodError: undefined method destroy for nil:NilClass` on above line which I mentioned in my question. What could be the reason?

Comment: you are not calling destroy in the code you show, but the problem should be that: 1. user is not logged in, 2. if user is logged in, user has not a playlist with id `params[:id]`, you can check your db or use `rails console`

Comment: I am using this piece of code to see it console `logger.debug @play_like` but it always return `#<Playlist:0xba33f1c>`. Why does this return meaningless kind of output?

Comment: you are printing an instance of class `Playlist`, `Playlist` is the name of the class, `0x...` is the memory position I think. Maybe you want to use `log.debug @play_like.inspect`, but I am not sure about the output.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, everything is an object, and objects have methods. Objects also have types.

Your top-level object there is `current_user`. This is an instance of some class - you can find out what kind by looking at `current_user.class`. I suspect you're going to find that it's an instance of `User`.

So, you find where your `User` is defined. This is likely a model, defined in `app/models/user.rb`. This model will specify a number of attributes and associations. In this case, you likely have a `has_many :playlists` association. What this does is set up an association between a `User` instance and a number of `Playlist` instances. Given a user instance, `user_instance.playlists` accesses this association. Your `Playlist` model will have a `user_id` field that associates a playlist with a user record. You can read more about associations [in the relevant documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Finally, this association will have a number of methods from Rails. ActiveRecord has a standard set of finders, as well as some "magic" finders like `find_by_id`, which infer the field to find from based on the method name. `find_by_id(params[:id])` is functionally equivalent to something like `find_by(:id => params[:id])`, but it's a little more English-y. You can read more about this in the Dynamic Finders method of [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html).

`find_by_id` will generate the SQL necessary to find the playlist records with that ID that also have a `user_id` matching `current_user`'s ID. If it finds a matching record, it will instantiate a Playlist record with the data it retrieved and return it. If no matching record is found, it will return nil.

Comment: Please see the comments which I gave for juanpastas answer.

Comment: I don't think you're getting the error at the line you think you are. What's the top of your stack trace say?